# My www- files differ from my non-www files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am having some issues that I've never had before. I've had issues in the past with flash content not working on my site at times, and found that the problem was a crossdomain. That is, flash content would load on www.mysite.com but not mysite.com. So the solution was simply to create a crossdomain.xml file with the appropriate permissions.

I'm having a seemingly similar issue now. My mysite.com/css/styles.css file differs from the www.mysite.com/css/styles.css file. Now when I upload, the css is updated at the www. site, but not the non-www site. I don't understand how the non-www site css file was updated to begin with, but now the new version does not overwrite the old one there (but does at www.)

Is this an htaccess issue?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a 301 redirect? http://www.squidoo.com/301

Usually you redirect the non www to the www site or viceversa